# How to correct add an index on firebase realtime rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Hi guys I've been trying to add an specific index for this specific structure:

[image: Firebase database structure]

But the fact is that after I've read the docs from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#variables) I still couldn't find a way on how to accomplish the task to add the index to the  "uid_to" at /c000000001_talks and c000000002_talks and the others.

Just for understanding this c000000001_ is the prefix of a tenant, so ever tenant has its own prefix on the tables.

I've seen that firebase recommends to create in two levels like tenant\c000000001\talks
tenant\c000000001\members

But this structure already exist and its in production we can't change it anymore.

Comment: Why are you trying to add index? Usually you can see in the firebase function logs a complain/suggestion when an index is recommended, just check the logs and see where is it needed to optimize your database. Also, I have been using index on child values, not parent UID's, but I can't see one in the structure above

Comment: Hi @Mocas I'm trying just because the firebase is complaining about it, on every tenant for the same tables. 
Here is one of his complains: @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "uid_to" at /c000000002_talks to your security rules for better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not putting the index on the correct branch on your rules

Try this:

```
RED-CROSSED_PARENT:
                  {
                   "$talksID": 
                              {
                               ".indexOn": "uid_to"
                               }
                  }
```

Because your talks are the same structure, ideally you would have them under the same parent 'Talks' so the "indexOn" only apply to Talks children

```
RED-CROSSED_PARENT:
                  {
                  Talks:{
                         "$talksID": 
                                   {
                                   ".indexOn": "uid_to"
                                   }
                        }
                   }
```

I am assuming that you know how to get to rules on your database

Comment: The problem is that this hint also apply to c000000003_talks, c000000004_talks, and go on, this way I've done and it works. But as new customers subscribe we have to manually add the new index...

Comment: Hey @Mocas I`ve tested with the first approach and it seems it works. Well test on other tenants to confirm.

Comment: Yeap it works just add to the rules: "$talksId": {
        ".indexOn": ["uid_to"]
      }

Comment: I`m only afraid that in the same level we have other tables like c000000003_connected_users, c000000003_members ...